# ZeroTurnaround Process Executor (zt-exec) processes waiting for input on infinite loop, how?

Tags: java, python, processbuilder

Using [zt-exec](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec) I would like to know how it can write/read to a process which is waiting for console input on an infinite loop, as well as responding using its console out?

I believe the easiest way to describe this is with a Python script:

```
while(True):
    javaSaid = raw_input("Hey Java, Say Something: ") ##wait for input from java
    print "Python Heard Java Say: " +str(javaSaid) ##java needs to be able to get this output
```

Note: Executing the python process multiple times is what I am trying to avoid as the initialization time on the real python script makes this unacceptable.

Comment: Have you figured out how?

Answer (score 1):

You need to call `redirectInput` as well as `redirectOutput` on `ProcessExecutor`.

Have a look at [ProcessExecutorInputStreamTest.java](https://github.com/zeroturnaround/zt-exec/blob/d9e4fdf61d15ab7492b6bdf40376536aebaaf6ff/src/test/java/org/zeroturnaround/exec/test/ProcessExecutorInputStreamTest.java). It's just an example. It writes data to the process input vie `PipedOutputStream -> PipedInputStream -> ProcessExecutor` and read data from the process via an `OutputStream`.